# remove part of string after delimiter in php

Tags: php, wordpress, string, substr

I have seen other
I have a string `" cccc cccc - fff"`

I need to return `"cccc cccc"` I don't need to delimiter too 
 I tried to echo the result of
  `substr($mystring , 0, strpos($mystring , "-"));` 
but it return nothing
I also tried

```
list($result, $trash) =split('-', $mystring);

 echo $result;
 echo $trash;
```

resulted returned the main string and trash resulted nothing

Update:
i'm using wordpress and for some reason it is not working.
I need to trim my title, i'm using get_the_title() and i'm trying to trim it

```
$mystring =get_the_title();

list($result, $trash) =split('-', $mystring); 
 echo $result;
```

Comment: The `substr()` code works.. (when there is a dash).

Comment: there is a dash i my title and it is not working

Comment: Then make sure its an actual ASCII hyphen (`-`) and not one of the other variants (depends on the used encoding). E.g. `‒`, `–`, `—` `―`.. If that's the case then regex might be a viable solution.

Comment: and how to do that?!

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? "For some reason it is not working" is a pretty broad description of your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading ShiraNai7's comment, it seems you need a regex based solution.  I've tested my pattern against your input as well as ShiraNai7's different versions of the dash.

Pattern ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1avCTA/2)): `/^ +\K[\w ]+(?= )/`

Explanation:

- `/` - start pattern
- `^` - start match from start of the string
- `+` - match one or more spaces characters (there is a literal space before the + sign)
- `\K` - disregard previously matched characters, start matching from this point.
- `[\w ]+` - match one or more characters that are alpha-numeric, underscore, or space
- `(?= )` - a "positive lookahead" doesn't capture what it matches; used to halt the match before final space that precedes delimiter (dash/hyphen/whatever)
- `/` - end pattern

Method ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f362ccec95caf594ef28e16505f6cf2675cb592)):

```
$my_string=" cccc cccc - fff";
$result=preg_match('/^ +\K[\w ]+(?= )/',$my_string,$out)?$out[0]:$my_string;  // if can't extract, use full string
echo $result;
```

Output:

```
cccc cccc
```

---

If this was my project, I would not be using regex, I would be using [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) (again, just be sure you are using the appropriate hyphen character).

```
echo trim(strstr($my_string,'-',true));
```

`strstr()` with the "before_needle" (3rd parameter) set to `true` will return the substring that precedes the hyphen.  Then simply `trim()` off the leading and trailing white-spaces.

Alternatively, explode is just as effective, it just generates an array before extracting the desired substring:

```
echo trim(explode('-',$my_string,2)[0]);  // don't bother generating more than one element - you only want the first anyhow
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$mystring=" cccc cccc - fff";
$result = explode("-",  $mystring);

echo $result[0];
```

The Output is :   cccc cccc

Comment: result[0] returns the first letter of the string and not the whole string

Comment: The output is  cccc cccc

Answer (score 1):

Try this, check the **[live demo here](https://eval.in/794749)**.

```
echo trim(explode("-", " cccc cccc - fff -888")[0]);
```

Comment: for some weird reason it's not trimming in my machine, i'm using wordpress and it is returning the whole string

Comment: wordpress is also write in php. just show your code here.

Comment: i did update it the only difference is i'm using get_the_title(); to get the string. the code is exactly the same

Answer (score -1):

substr(" cccc cccc - fff", 0, 10)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it.  What if the prefix is shorter, or longer? I would assume your code isn't working any more for that situation

Comment: This piece of code will work for fixed format string. like when you are fetching the data from DB like this("2021-06-24 15:57:12") u should do nothing like explode or split or regex. Simply just find the position of starting and ending will give you the exact output.Further more for dynamic problem you must have to explode or split or regex as far as i know.

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer by editing it